# Reducing $u_t = u_{xx} + u$ to the heat equation, and finding a solution

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

Been given the following problem:

> Consider the PDE
>   $$u_t = u_{xx} + u, 0 < x < 1$$
>   $$u(0, t) = u(1, t) = 0, t > 0$$
>   $$u(x, 0) = f(x), 0 < x < 1$$
>   (a) Use the method of separation of variables to obtain a solution for $v(x,t)$, where $ u(x,t) = e^{rt}v(x, t)$ , choosing $r$ such that the above problem reduces to the heat equation, and then, obtain
>   the solution for $u(x, t)$

How would I find $r$ to reduce the problem to a heat equation as asked? Cannot seem to find this information anywhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With

$u_t = u_{xx} + \beta u, \tag 1$

and

$u(x, t) = e^{rt} v(x, t), \tag 2$

we have

$u_t = re^{rt}v + e^{rt}v_t \tag 3$

and

$u_{xx} = e^{rt}v_{xx}; \tag 4$

then (1) becomes

$re^{rt}v + e^{rt}v_t = e^{rt}v_{xx} + \beta e^{rt} v; \tag 5$

we may cancel the factor $e^{rt}$:

$rv + v_t = v_{xx} + \beta v, \tag 6$

and re-arrange things slightly to obtain

$v_t = v_{xx} + (\beta - r) v; \tag 7$

if we now choose

$r = \beta, \tag 8$

we find that (7) yields

$v_t = v_{xx}, \tag 9$

the usual heat equation.

We conform to the requirement of the present question but setting

$r = 1, \tag{10}$

whence

$u(x, t) = e^t v(x, t), \tag{11}$

or

$v(x, t) = e^{-t} u(x, t). \tag{12}$